# Is there a resource (connection) pool that automatically returns borrowed resources (connections) when they are not needed?

Tags: java, jdbc, threadpool, connection-pooling, pool

Is there a resource (connection) pool that automatically of the borrowed resources (connections) when they are not needed?

I frequently encountered situations where Java software
has bugs due to pooled connections not being returned (closed). Mostly built by external vendors, where I provide the long term maintenance services. I would like for the pool to automatically return the connection
if it is idle (not used) for the specified amount of time (seconds).
As long as the connection is used by the same thread, it should remain allocated
to that thread, but if the thread has not made use of the connection for more than a few (5) seconds since the last call completed,
the connection should get automatically returned to the pool.

I have done the prototype on a commercial web server with commercial RDBMS
and the performance is stellar in our production.
Since the pooled connections are sticky to the thread
and the web server already uses thread pools,
there is minimal switching of connections between different threads.
Hence, performance is better than when using the traditional borrow and return approach,
as once the connection is borrowed by a thread, it usually
stays allocated to the same thread for quite a while,
as it is frequently being used.

Apart from JDBC connections, this approach has worked well
for other heavy pooled resources, such as JSON parsers,
HTTP connections or Date Formatters. If you have fewer connections in the pool that parallel threads on the server, there isn't much value, as you won't be able to run that many
threads in parallel anyway, since there are not enough connections.
So why not have as many connections as many parallel threads.

Some existing pools can release connection after a period of inactivity,
but the servlet that does not release its connections,
would quickly exhaust all available connections,
if it encounters the right conditions and it gets a large number of requests. With the new thread-sticky connections that is not the case,
as the thread that does not release the connection,
get the same connection again on borrow.

My question, what would be the main reason
not to use this approach, as I find it a much better performing on servers
that are reusing threads and maintaining thread pools.

Comment: Down-voting without providing rationale or a reason is not the constructive approach to discussion on this forum.

Comment: C3P0, Hikari, more

Comment: You can try out HikariCP - https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP
It has multiple configuration properties for lifetinme of threads

Comment: I did this to replace HikariCP. Repeated entries into the same servlet kept borrowing new connections. HikariCP does not implement thread stickiness, so if connections are not correctly released it quickly runs out of connections.

Comment: You could look at the `removeAbandoned*` settings of Apache DBCP.

Answer (score 0):

> I frequently encountered situations where Java software has bugs due to pooled connections not being returned (closed).

This is a problem with your own app code accessing the database, not a problem with your connection pool.

Every client app is responsible for closing the JDBC database connection.

The try-with-resources syntax on Java was invented to make this easy. You can list resources within the parentheses if they implement the [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface. Such classes include [`java.sql.Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html), `Statement`, `ResultSet`, and so on.

```java
DataSource dataSource = … 
…
try
(
   Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection() ;
)
{
    … use your database connection 
}
// At this point your database connection has been closed, whether having completed its work successfully or whether an exception was thrown. 
// If the connection came from a pool, the connection will actually be returned to the pool rather than actually closed, per policies of that particular pool implementation.
```

You asked:

> if the thread has not made use of the connection for more than a few (5) seconds since the last call completed, the connection should get automatically returned to the pool.

This would be unwise. You would simply be putting wallpaper over a hole in the wall, masking the real problem rather than solving it. You should be auto-closing connections as seen above. And then investigate and resolve any cases of code hanging and connections not being returned. With your approach you would be ignoring such faults. And any temporarily delayed code might then resume to use a connection in use by other code.

---

By the way, asking for software recommendations is explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow. For that, see the sister site [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: It is the issue with outsources developer pool our guys prefer to use. There are frequent issues I need to deal with. It was easier to create solution that automatically manages the releasing of connections and makes them stick to the thread while it is alive. In that scenario there are very few borrow and return actions.

Comment: BTW, I asked, what is the rationale not to implement this approach. Asking about existing solutions was just the part of my case, that nobody have done it before.

Comment: @mindiga My Answer gives that rationale: The JDBC client should *always* be closing the connection. Any failure to do so is a serious flaw in that app. It makes no sense to have a connection pool rip away a connection from the client code.

Comment: thanks for the answer. The question was why not to implement the pool that sticks connection to a thread, so that thread does not have to borrow and return it on every servlet entry. If I have the thread servicing 100 request per second, that is 100 borrow and 100 return. With the new approach, no borrow and no return, but still pool can re-allocate connections if the servlet is inactive or the thread dies.

Comment: with try-with-resources you need to have try catch blocks all over your code and closing connection is not the right response to every error. Some errors are not caused by the connection, while in other errors connection is not even created, so there is no need to close it. Why have each developer having to worry about it, when you can have the pool take care of it in a consistent way.

Comment: @mindiga The correct way of working is to use try-with-resources over the unit-of-work. In the case of a servlet, that unit of work should span **at most** the entire request duration, but usually only a part of the request (or maybe multiple units-of-work in a request). Using try-with-resources ensures the connection is closed (== returned to the pool) at the end of that unit of work. Not wanting to use try-with-resources is what causes your problem (that said, there are connection pools that will forcibly remove connections that aren't returned, but that should be a last resort).

Comment: I am interested in performance boost cumming from having connection sticky to a thread, so we do not have to do borrow and return across requests in close chronological proximity. HikariCP keeps thread local connections to achieve this partly. I do not see a value it bouncing the same connection between threads and dealing with connection activation and recovery and having to switch current context. Plus all statement pre-compiled plans and data caching goes out of the window is you change thread. I am getting 3 times performance boost over HikariCP.